# Не могу вывести информацию о пользователе (VkNet)

Tags: c#, vknet

Я хочу вывести информацию с моей страницы, делаю я это вот таким способом:

```
var vk = new VkApi();
        vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams { AccessToken = "тут токен приложения" });
        var user = vk.Users.Get(new long[] { 327883191 }, VkNet.Enums.Filters.ProfileFields.Counters).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName);
        Console.WriteLine(user.HomeTown);
        Console.WriteLine(user.HomePhone);
        Console.WriteLine(user.Online);
```

Мне пытались объяснить, что этот метод принимает fileds, и мне их нужно передать. Но я не понял одного - куда мне их передать?

Comment: Судя по описанию https://vknet.github.io/vk/users/get/ вам надо вместо , VkNet.Enums.Filters.ProfileFields.Counters указать поля. Напишите VkNet.Enums.Filters.ProfileFieldsи поставив точку посмотрите что вам на автокомплите будет предлагаться, вероятно   вероятно это будет что-то отсюда: Доступные значения: photo_id, verified, sex, bdate, city, country, home_town, has_photo, .... https://vk.com/dev/users.get

Comment: Ну да, предлагаются эти поля. Вот пишу я VkNet.Enums.Filters.ProfileFields.Online например. Мне нужно ещё HomeTown и HomePhone. Как мне их передать?